# Sending href and id of clicked link from page to django using Ajax

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I have an on click JQuery event handler that I want to use to send the href and id of any clicked link to my Django server. But I am having a hard time finding a good tutorial/info about using Django with Ajax.

Let's say I want to send the id and href of the link, have Django check if the link has https, and send the href along with a message back as a response.

Something like:

```
$("a").on("click", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if(e.target.href){
        let id = e.target.id; 
        let href = e.target.href;
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "/nameOfFunction/", 
            data: {"id":id, "href":href}, 
            type: "POST", 
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.msg=="yes"){alert(response.href+" is Secure")}
                else{alert(response.href+" is Not Secure")}    
            }, 
            error:function(error) { 
                console.log(error); 
            } 
        }); 
    }
});
```

```
def nameOfFunction(request):
    if ("https" in request.POST.get("href")):
        msg = "yes"
    else:
        msg = "no"

    return ({"msg":msg, "href":href})
```

Can someone help me fix this so that it works?

Comment: What happens with this code?

Comment: This is code I was using in Flask(which is a much simpler framework).The above probably wont work mainly because it is missing some items like a csrf token. Also I am unsure what form should data be sent in.

Comment: So, did you read the comprehensive docs on [CSRF in Ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#ajax)?

Comment: yes, still doesnt help much. I already added ```csrfmiddlewaretoken: {{% csrf_token %}}``` to  my ajax request

Comment: But nothing in that doc says to do that.

Comment: Other sites mentioned ajax being required to have csrf token. Do you have any experience using ajax with django?

Comment: Yes. That document says *exactly* what to do. It did *not* say to do what you put in the previous comment.

Comment: I dont see them sending an object though? I fail to understand how I can use this information for my case.

Comment: What do you mean, sending an object? You said your issue was with csrf. That doc explains how to get and send the csrf token in Ajax.

Comment: My question is what's in the question body, csrf is one of the missing things. I have no idea whether this works or not because I need to put this in several html sources (add as string to html then store) so I cant trial-and-error my way through this. I want someone who knows ajax-django to tell me how to do what I want to do (as asked in the question),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out:

index.html

```
$("a").on("click", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if(e.target.href){
        let id = e.target.id; 
        let href = e.target.href;
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "/nameOfFunction/", 
            data: JSON.stringify({"id":id, "href":href}), 
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftok);
                        }, 
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.msg=="yes"){alert(response.href+" is Secure")}
                else{alert(response.href+" is Not Secure")}    
            }, 
            error:function(error) { 
                console.log(error); 
            } 
        }); 
    }
});
```

where csrftok is a variable with the value you get by adding this to the html:

```
{% csrf_token %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        var csrftok = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
                    });  
</script>
```

views.py

```
def nameOfFunction(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        received = ast.literal_eval(request.body.decode())
        id= received['id']
        link= received['link']
    if "https" in link:
        return JsonResponse({'msg': "yes", "href":link})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'msg': "no", "href":link})
```

urls.py(add this code)

```
path('nameOfFunction/', views.nameOfFunction)
```